# Which Pokemon have had changes to stats, abilities or their movepool in Pokemon Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

Most generations of Pokemon see changes to older Pokemon's stats, abilities, as well as movepools.

Which Pokemon received changes in Sun/Moon when compared to the 6th generation games? What were the changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are the gains and nerfs that I know of so far:

## Abilities

- **Beartic**
  Gained: [**Slush Rush**](http://serebii.net/abilitydex/slushrush.shtml) (Speed Boost in Hail)
- **Boldore and Roggenrola**
  Gained: [**Weak Armor**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/weakarmor.shtml) (Lowers Defense, but raises Speed two stages when hit with a Physical attack)
- **Entei**
  Changed: Flash Fire -> [**Inner Focus**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/innerfocus.shtml) (Can't be flinched)
- **Gengar**
  Changed: Levitate -> [**Cursed Body**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/cursedbody.shtml) (May disable the enemy's move when hit with a move that makes contact)
- **Gigalith**
  Gained: [**Sand Stream**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/sandstream.shtml) (Starts a Sandstorm)
- **Pelipper**
  Gained: [**Drizzle**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/drizzle.shtml) (Starts Raining)
- **Raikou**
  Changed: Volt Absorb -> [**Inner Focus**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/innerfocus.shtml) (Can't be flinched)
- **Suicune**
  Changed: Water Absorb -> [**Inner Focus**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/innerfocus.shtml) (Can't be flinched)
- **Torkoal**
  Gained: [**Drought**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/drought.shtml)  (Starts Intense Sunlight)
- **Vanilluxe**
  Gained: [**Snow Warning**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/snowwarning.shtml) (Starts a Hailstorm)

## Stats

- **Alakazam (Mega)**
  SpDef +10 (95 -> 105)
- **Arbok**
  Atk +10 *(85 -> 95)*
- **Ariados**
  SpDef +10 *(60 -> 70)*
- **Beartic**
  Atk +20 *(110 -> 130)*
- **Chimecho**
  HP +10  *(65 -> 75)*
  Def +10  *(70 -> 80)*
  SpDef +10 *(80 -> 90)*
- **Corsola**
  HP +10 *(55 -> 65)*
  Def +10 *(85 -> 95)*
  SpDef +10 *(85 -> 95)*
- **Crustle**
  Atk +10 *(95 -> 105)*
- **Cryogonal**
  HP +10 *(70 -> 80)*
  Def +20 *(30 -> 50)*
- **Delcatty**
  Spe +20 *(70 -> 90)*
- **Dodrio**
  Spe +10 *(100 -> 110)*
- **Dugtrio**
  Atk +20 *(80 -> 100)*
- **Electrode**
  Spe +10 *(140 -> 150)*
- **Exeggutor**
  SpDef +10 *(65 -> 75)*
- **Farfetch’d**
  Atk +25 *(65 -> 90)*
- **Illumise**
  Def +20 *(55 -> 75)*
  SpDef *(75 -> 85)*
- **Lunatone**
  HP +20 *(70 -> 90)*
- **Magcargo**
  HP +10 *(50 -> 60)*
  Sp. Atk +10 *(80 -> 90)*
- **Mantine**
  HP +20 *(65 -> 85)*
- **Masquerain**
  Sp. Atk +20 *(80 -> 100)*
  Spe +20 *(60 -> 80)*
- **Noctowl**
  Sp. Atk +10 *(76 -> 86)*
- **Pelipper**
  **Sp. Atk +10 *(85 -> 95)*
- **Qwilfish**
  Def +10 *(75 -> 85)*
- **Solrock**
  HP +20 *(70 -> 90)*
- **Swellow**
  Sp. Atk +25 *(50 -> 75)*
- **Volbeat**
  Def +20 *(55 -> 75)*
  SpDef *(75 -> 85)*
- **Woobat**
  HP +10 (55 -> 65)

## Movepool

- **Bellossom**
  Gained: [**Quiver Dance**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/quiverdance.shtml)
  (Bug - Status - Boosts Sp Atk, Sp Def & Speed by one stage)
- **Dodrio**
  Gained: [**Swords Dance**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/swordsdance.shtml)
  (Normal - Status - Boosts Atk by two stages)
  Gained: [**Jump Kick**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/jumpkick.shtml)
  (Fighting - Physical - 100BP/90% Acc - If this misses, the user takes half max HP in damage)
- **Flygon**
  Gained: [**Dragon Dance**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/dragondance.shtml)
  (Dragon - Status - Boosts Attack and Speed by 1 stage)
- **Mantine**
  Gained: [**Roost**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/roost.shtml)
  (Flying - Status - Heals up to 50% Max HP. While perched, the Pokemon is no longer Flying-type
- **Noctowl**
  Gained: [**Moonblast**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/moonblast.shtml)
  (Fairy - Special 95BP/100% Acc - May lower target's Special Attack)
- **Sharpedo**
  Gained: [**Psychic Fangs**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/psychicfangs.shtml)
  (Psychic - Physical 85BP/100% Acc - Destroys Enemy Light Screens/Reflects)
- **Stoutland**
  Gained: [**Psychic Fangs**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/psychicfangs.shtml)
  (Psychic - Physical 85BP/100% Acc - Destroys Enemy Light Screens/Reflects)
- **Wormadam**
  Gained: [**Quiver Dance**](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-sm/quiverdance.shtml)
  (Bug - Status - Boosts Sp Atk, Sp Def & Speed by one stage)

## References

- [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/updatedstats.shtml)
- [Bitbag](http://www.thebitbag.com/pokemon-sun-moon-leaks-full-new-pokemon-list-full-buff-nerf-list-new-abilities-new-moves/200468)